# Centos 7 Mysterious Reboots

Tags: centos

this is my first post here. I've been dealing with an issue where a Centos 7 box is rebooting every Sunday night at 20:03 and 20:31. I don't see anything in Cron for any user. The messages logs aren't really giving me a clue. I would have thought it would be simple to find since it occurs at the same time every week.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked `/etc/cron.d/` and the other `/etc/cron.*` directories too? The messages logs (and/or `journalctl`) should indicate if the system is executing a controlled shutdown; if the system is getting powered down externally, you would see only routine messages up to the point of powerdown, and then the start-up messages, with no indication of shutdown. If the hardware is server-grade, it might have a management processor with its own power event log.

Comment: This is a Dell server.  Yes .. I checked to see if the reboots were invoked from cron and they aren't. This started on March 13, 2022. I'm really scratching my head on this one.